# Ionic 3/4, ERROR TypeError: _co.toBoarding is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I get an error using Ionic 3/4, I get error to navigate between 2 component, I don't know why, 3 months ago was fine using Ionic, but today I get an error. I use lazyload to navigate 2 component.

This is error that I get :

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.toBoarding is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (HomePage.html:12)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
    at core.js:10629
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2628)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

and this is my full script :

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>
    <button ion-button (click)="toBoarding()">Button</button>
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  toBoarding() {
    this.navCtrl.push('BoardingPage');
  }
}
```

boarding.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>boarding</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

boarding.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-boarding',
  templateUrl: 'boarding.html',
})
export class BoardingPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad BoardingPage');
  }

}
```

So, What should I do to solve this problem, or you have solving to solve this problem, please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Just stop server and start again. That will solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is compiler error of ionic. You will get it when your function is not compiled properly. Just stop the application and again serve it